# Do a Google voice search with Belkin CarAudio Connect Bluetooth on a Sony Xperia

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio, hands-free

I have a non-rooted Sony Xperia running Android 4.3 and I have recently have bought a Belkin CarAudio Connect AUX with Bluetooth. It connects fine and it all works however it left me wanting more. Currently pressing the button on the CarAudio Connect pauses and plays the audio, a feature that I wish to keep. However, I was hoping that a double tab or a long press can do a Google voice search so I can call or text people (or find out important information like the height of the Eiffel Tower) while driving.

How would I set this up? I have tried 'Bluetooth Launch' from the Play store but it didn't do anything and I couldn't find any similar apps. I was thinking a Tasker task or a similar app but I don't know how to set it up or what action to look for.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) and the [AutoVoice Addon](http://www.appbrain.com/app/autovoice/com.joaomgcd.autovoice). From the addon's description:

> Control your Android device with your voice, now even via your Bluetooth headset! You can even redirect all audio to your Bluetooth headset and also react to your Bluetooth headset button and do whatever action you want with it in Tasker.

Basically, you create a new profile in *Tasker* to activate *AutoVoice* (e.g. shaking the device, pressing the camera button, using a shortcut to the given task, whatever), which then acts on keywords even by [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) match (there's also a "permanent listening mode" which you could enable on conditions like "power plugged in plus Bluetooth connected to car"). There are plenty of ways to realize different things with it, a full how-to would go much beyond the scope of this site :) You can even have *AutoVoice* triggering *Google Now*, if you like.

To go deeper into this topic, let me give you some links:

- [How to use Google Now to Trigger Tasker Tasks - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6Woh20ullI)
- [[TUTORIAL] Merge Xposed, Tasker, Autovoice and Google Now to use phone only by voice](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2657759)
- [AutoVoice Beginner: Setting Up Voice Recognition - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SfA9mE6kvko)
- [Voice Control Your Phone with Tasker and AutoVoice - XDA developer TV](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/voice-control-your-phone-with-tasker-and-autovoice-xda-developer-tv/)

For more, simply google for "autovoice howto" :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer however it probably a bit more complex than I was aiming for. I was more hoping for 'When bluetooth button is pressed then launch Google Now' instead of writing all my own commands. Saying that I found that there is a long press function on my hands free just that I have to release to make it activate (I was pressing so long waiting for something to happen but it only turned off) and I got it to activate Google Now, now just have a problem that behind the lock screen it only allows calls and no other commands.

Comment: Well, basically it is that (just setting up one task to have AutoVoice launching GoogleNow, and than voice-interact with GoogleNow) – everything else was just to "show off what's possible". As for the lockscreen issue, I would again argue with *Tasker*: "When docked → Disable Lockscreen" (that's part of my "Nightstand Mode").